# What's the difference between src vs attr(src, ...)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, src, attr

What is the difference between src and attr('src', variableName)? It seems to me that I'm doing the same thing. Assigning a value to an image source attribute.

I'm writing some jQuery and in one place src works, but not the other, and in the other place, attr('src', variableName) works and the other doesn't.

Here's my code:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    function imageSnap() {
        $( 'p img' ).each( function() {

            // Store image selector
            var image = $( this );

            // Store image source
            var imageSrc = image.attr('data-src');

            // Create new image and assign image source
            var newImage = new Image();
            newImage.src = imageSrc; //                    HERE // works
            //newImage.attr( 'src', imageSrc );                 // doesn't work

            // Execute on image load
            image.load( function() {

                // Store native image dimensions
                var nativeWidth = newImage.width;
                var nativeHeight = newImage.height;


                // more code stuffs


                console.log( 'nativeWidth ' + nativeWidth );
                console.log( 'nativeHeight ' + nativeHeight );
            });

            // Load image
            //image.src = imageSrc;                   AND HERE // doesn't work
            image.attr('src', imageSrc );                      // works
        });
    }

    // Execute on document ready
    imageSnap();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var newImage = new Image();
newImage.src = imageSrc; // works
//newImage.attr( 'src', imageSrc ); // doesn't work
```

This doesn't work because `var newImage = new Image();` is not jquery syntax. It is therefore not creating a reference to a jquery object, so the method `.attr()` which is a jquery method  will not work. But `.src` would because that is standard js.

```
var image = $( this );
```

This is referencing a jquery object. So when you later call `.attr()` on it, it will assign as expected.

Comment: That makes since. Would you say that's a bad thing to do them different ways? I can't seem to find a way to create a new image with jQuery.

Comment: `$('<img>')` would create a new image node. Then you can populate it with attributes. I would say consistency is good in general. If you're using jquery already, it makes sense to use jquery syntax when you can for maintainability.

Answer (score 3):

They're the same thing, but the first thing (`.src`) doesn't work because `$(this)` is pulled from a jQuery selector (`$(this)` is your `image` variable) and `.src` is a method from native JavaScript that jQuery doesn't recognize when you use its selectors.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is, `newImage` is not the same object as `image`.  The first is an object of type `Image()` that has a variable `src` while the second is a JQuery collection object that has the `src` attribute somewhere buried inside and accessible via the `attr` function.